# Filebeat from elasticsearch will not filter

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

filebeat is not filtering messages. Below is the message

```
"message": "172.31.25.199 - - [07/Jun/2016:13:07:26 +0000] \"GET /api HTTP/1.1\" 200 27 \"-\" \"ELB-HealthChecker/1.0\"",
```

I want to filter for "ELB-HealthChecker/1.0\" and exclude.  Yet I see the messages.  Why?

```
filebeat:
  prospectors:
    -
      paths:
        - "/tmp/api.log"
        - "/var/log/nginx/access.log"
        - "/var/log/nginx/error.log"
      fields:
        type: log
      exclude_lines: ["^ELB-HealthChecker"]
output:
  logstash:
    hosts: ["127.0.0.1:5043"]
```

Comment: In regex, `^` means a line that starts with... In your example, your line doesn't start with ELB-HealthChecker, maybe you should try something like `*ELB-HealthChcker*`

Answer (score 0):

As the comment from Or Weinberger said, the problem comes from your exclude_lines configuration. The `^` means the lines has to start with "ELB-HealthChecker" to match the regex and be dropped. Since ELB-HealthChecker is in the middle of the line, you should use something like :

```
.*ELB-HealthChecker.*
```